# Jquery UI autocomplete wont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Jquery UI autocomplete wont work,what could be wrong?Here is the code.Thank you

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylez.css"/>
         <script type="text/jscript">
            $(document).ready( function(){
          $('.searchfield').autocomplete({source:["salim","keli","ally"]});
    }); 
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
<div>
            <label><b>Search</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="searchfield" size="52"/>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `<script>` tag needs the closing tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<script type="text/jscript">` => `<script type="text/javascript">`

also the `script` tag is not self closing. You always need to provide a closing `</script>` tag.

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tHqwq/).